# Getting "public variable" in a "private method" using CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, private-methods, public-method

I have the following code:

```
class Example

  @text = 'Hello world! ;)'

  getText = ->
    @text

  constructor: ->
    alert(getText())

### Instance ###
example = new Example
```

This will return 'undefined', Is there any way to make it return the `@text` content?

http://jsfiddle.net/vgS3y/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common error in CoffeeScript.  Look at the compiled JavaScript:

```
Example = (function() {
  var getText;

  Example.text = 'Hello world! ;)';

  getText = function() {
    return this.text;
  };

  function Example() {
    alert(getText());
  }

  return Example;

})();
```

Using `@` in the class definition creates a static method or variable.  That is, it's attached to the class object.

If you're trying to make it an instance variable, set it in your constructor.

```
constructor: ->
  @text = 'Hello world! ;)'
  alert(getText())
```

If you're trying to access the static property, refer to the class name.

```
getText = ->
  Example.text
```